# SDK manager can be same for both android studio and eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio-2.0

I am using Android Studio and i want to install eclipse for a while, can i use the  same SDk path for both? Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No problem you can use the same SDK path , it will not affect eclipse and android studio

Comment: I have already installed different sdk paths for both, is there any chances to keep same sdk paths now?

Comment: Now,i have given same path but,sdk manager tools are not updated as in androidstudio.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set up a common SDK, for example put your SDK folder at the following location C:\Android\sdk

Link SDK in your Android Studio, go to File->Project Structure->Android SDK and point the C:\Android\sdk in Android SDK location.

Link SDK in your Eclipse ADT, go to Eclipse->Preferences->Android and change the SDK Location to C:\Android\sdk

*Restart both Eclipse and Android Studio

Comment: I have already installed different sdk for both android studio and eclipse,can i use the same procedure what you have said above now?

Comment: Now,i have given same path but,sdk manager tools are not updated as in androidstudio.

Comment: yes you can, just in eclipse put the sdk path similar to that of android studio